foreign language changing chapter headings
I have an english document and in the bibliography have one reference in Russian.  When the document compiles all the chapter headings are changed to russian.  I have tried many redundant steps try to force english
\documentclass[russian,english]{report}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}



\begin{thebibliography}{WW}
\bibitem[BS]{Brown}Brown, D.E.\ and Sneddon I., {\em A Collection of Problems on a Course on Mathematical Analysis}, translation  from the original Russian of  
{\selectlanguage{russian}{Сьорник
эадак  ло кирсу математического аналиэа}}
(Sbornik zadach po kursu maternaticheskogo analiza), Gostekhizdat, Moscow, 1965.
\end{thebibliography}

I have also tried  ...original Russian of
Сьорник
эадак  ло кирсу математического аналиэа
(Sbornik zadach po kursu maternaticheskogo analiza), Gostekhizdat, Moscow, 1965.
...original Russian of {\foreignlanguage{russian}{
Сьорник
эадак  ло кирсу математического аналиэа}}
(Sbornik zadach po kursu maternaticheskogo analiza), Gostekhizdat, Moscow, 1965.
\newenvironment{russian_text}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

\begin{russian_text}{  
Сьорник
эадак  ло кирсу математического аналиэа}\end{russian_text}
(Sbornik zadach po kursu maternaticheskogo analiza), Gostekhizdat, Moscow, 1965.

Same result.
I am running everything in overleaf.

Do not show only snippets.  Make a small but complete example that demonstrates your problem and the we can use as test.

Unrelated: are you sure that it is Сьорник and not Сборник? At least the transliteration seems not to match.

Off-topic: Is maternaticheskogo the correct transliteration of математического? Shouldn't rn be m?

Also off-topic: I think it would be very helpful to provide a bit more bibliographic information for this entry. For one, do please mention the author of the original Russian version, i.e., G.N. Berman. After all, Sneddon and Brown are "just" the translator and editor, respectively. In addition, do also provide some information about when and where the English translation was published. E.g., you could mention that the translation was published in 2014 by Elsevier, as volume 65 in their "International Series of Monographs on Pure and Applied Mathematics" series.

@JasperHabicht - Сборник is indeed correct. :-)

And another one: эадак should probably be задак and аналиэа should be анализа ...

Thanks for all the bibliography suggestions, but the latex problem remains. All the suggestions either produce no russian text or russian text with russian chapter headings.

@JohnJohnson Edit your original question and add a new MWE with what you are actually doing.

It's not at all clear what you're doing. On the one hand, your code claims to load the babel package; on the other, your code also contains the instructions \setdefaultlanguage and \setotherlanguage. These are not provided by the babel package; instead, they are provided by the polyglossia package -- which requires the use of either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile the document (along with the fontspec package). Using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile a document is perfectly fine, of course. It would be helpful, though, not to mix-and-mismatch babel and polyglossia terms.
I will tentatively assume that you're using the fontspec package along with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. I will further assume that you're interested in a babel-based solution. Please advise if these assumptions are inappropriate.
My main recommendations are (a) to use a font that provides both Latin and Cyrillic characters and (b) to encase any Cyrillic strings in \foreignlanguage{russian}{...} wrappers. That way, Russian-language rather than English-language hyphenation rules will be applied, if necessary, to these strings.
With this change in place, the information in the header lines will be using the default, i.e., English-language terminology:

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{book} % use a document class that generates header lines by default

\usepackage{iftex,fontspec}
\ifluatex % if we're using LuaLaTeX
  \setmainfont{FreeSerif} % choose a suitable font
\else % if we're using XeLaTeX
  \setmainfont{FreeSerif.otf}[ItalicFont=FreeSerifItalic.otf]
\fi

\usepackage[russian,english]{babel} % english is default language
\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{WW}

\bibitem[BS]{Brown}Brown, D.E. and Sneddon, I., \emph{A Collection of Problems 
  on a Course on Mathematical Analysis}, translation from the original Russian 
  of \foreignlanguage{russian}{Сьорник эадак ло кирсу математического аналиэа} 
  (Sbornik zadach po kursu maternaticheskogo analiza), Gostekhizdat, Moscow, 1965.

\end{thebibliography}

\lipsum[1-5] % filler text, to spill over to next page

\end{document}


If the only Russian text is this one, there is no need to request it explicitly in the preamble.  Lazy loading of languages was devised for cases like this.

This is just an alternative to the excelent answer by @Mico. The main font (ie, Computer Modern) is not changed, and a matching font is assigned to Russian. Since the Russian text is short, you can rely on lazy loading, ie, the language is loaded when requested, without an explicit declaration. The main language is set as a global option, so that other packages can recognize them. although this is not really necessary and can be declared as package option (but never at both places!). It works without changes in xetex and luatex (see below for pdftex).
\documentclass[english]{book}

\usepackage{babel}
\babelfont[russian]{rm}{NewComputerModern10}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{WW}

\bibitem[BS]{Brown}Brown, D.E. and Sneddon, I., \emph{A Collection of Problems 
  on a Course on Mathematical Analysis}, translation from the original Russian 
  of \foreignlanguage{russian}{Сьорник эадак ло кирсу математического аналиэа} 
  (Sbornik zadach po kursu matematicheskogo analiza), Gostekhizdat, Moscow, 1965.

\end{thebibliography}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.

\end{document}


With pdftex, the preamble reads:
\documentclass[english]{book}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

